# jqGrid pager problem after adding a row with addRowData

Tags: javascript, jquery-plugins, jqgrid

```
var index = 'id';
var ajaxResponse = [{id: 1, name: 'John', email: 'john@doe.co.uk'}, {id: 2, name: 'Michael', email: 'michael@example.com'}];
$('#grid').addRowData(index, ajaxResponse);
```

After adding multiple rows one by one the pager doesn't stick to the per page limitation, also the pager reports page 1 of 0.

After i hit the refresh button from the footer of the grid, i see the correct number of rows per page, and the correct number of pages.

Any ideas on how to fix?

Thanks.

Comment: Call refresh after add row jQuery("#grid").trigger("reloadGrid");

Comment: Probably there are misunderstanding how `addRowData` work. It's exactly to low-level modifications of jqGrid. You should explain more clear *what you want to do*. The names of both parameters of `addRowData` looks suspected. Do you try to fill the grid with JSON data received from the server? Why you use `addRowData` in the case? Could you include more code which you use (jqGrid definition and how you get the data from the server)? Including of the test JSON data (`ajaxResponse`) could be also very helpful.

Comment: Ok, now when i am adding multiple rows at a time, looks like reloadGrid works, maybe i was doing something wrong with single row, but thanks Naga

Comment: @NagaHarishM You should add that as an answer, so we can vote it and the OP can mark this question as answered. As this will help others having the same problem (as it would have helped me if I would have read your comment, sadly I went directly to answers, and after a while I reached to the same solution and was about to answer it here).

Comment: @MarianoDesanze Added to answer

Answer (score 1):

You don't posted the full code which you use. So I can only guess what you do.

If you have in `ajaxResponse` the full data which you use to fill the grid you can *create* the grid with data. You can use `data: ajaxResponse` together with `gridview: true`. In the case the whole grid will be created at once:

```
var mydata = [
        {id: 1, name: 'John', email: 'john@doe.co.uk'},
        {id: 2, name: 'Michael', email: 'michael@example.com'}
    ];

$("#list").jqGrid({
    datatype: 'local',
    data: mydata,
    colNames: ['Name', 'E-Mail'],
    colModel: [
        {name: 'name', width: 100},
        {name: 'email', width: 150}
    ],
    rowNum: 5,
    rowList: [5, 10, 20],
    pager: '#pager',
    gridview: true,
    rownumbers: true,
    sortname: 'name',
    sortorder: 'desc',
    caption: 'Just simple local grid',
    height: 'auto'
});
```

(see the demo [here](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/Nicolae1.htm))

If you get the data from the server in JSON format like this

```
[
    {"id": 1, "name": "John",    "email": "john@doe.co.uk"},
    {"id": 2, "name": "Michael", "email": "michael@example.com"}
]
```

you can set `url` parameter to the server URL which provide the data and use

```
$("#list").jqGrid({
    url: 'Nicolae2.json',
    datatype: 'json',
    jsonReader: {
        repeatitems: false,
        root: function (obj) { return obj; },
        page: function () { return 1; },
        total: function () { return 1; },
        records: function (obj) { return obj.length; }
    },
    loadonce: true,
    colNames: ['Name', 'E-Mail'],
    colModel: [
        {name: 'name', width: 100},
        {name: 'email', width: 150}
    ],
    rowNum: 5,
    rowList: [5, 10, 20],
    pager: '#pager',
    gridview: true,
    rownumbers: true,
    sortname: 'name',
    sortorder: 'asc',
    caption: 'Just simple local grid',
    height: 'auto'
});
```

to fill the grid per Ajax *directly* from the server. The only restriction that you have to provide correct sorted data. So I changed the `sortorder: 'desc'` from the previous example to `sortorder: 'asc'`. See the second demo [here](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/Nicolae2.htm).

Comment: what about this one? http://jsfiddle.net/yauhen/aY59T/9/
I want to add new row so it will appear on last page without changing current page.

I also periodically need to merge data in table with data comming from other location so I go over all data in grid compare ids with ids come from other location and want to add/delete records in grid. I don't want to refesh full grid because it could be lengthy. for example for knockoutjs sample http://jsfiddle.net/ZCJQw/1/ (see details here https://raw.github.com/gist/908284/8eea5b634a84f975688b5aa18159540a8c02a9c9/ko.gridBindingSpike.js)

Comment: @Yauhen.F: I don't full understand your requirements. Which `datatype` you has? How the grid will be filled? Whether the grid contains sorted data or not? Do you use `loadonce: true`? What would be the perfect look of the grid which you need and so on? So it would be better if you open new question where you described the full requirements and the scenario of the grid filling which you have.

Comment: @Yauhen.F Calling `$("#list").trigger('reloadGrid');` resolves that. Check: http://jsfiddle.net/protron/aY59T/33/

Comment: @MarianoDesanze: Yes, reloading could be an option. The problem is: I don't understand full *the scenario*, which you need to implement. It's important to know the `datatype` for example and whether you need to add one/some rows on **local** grid only or to post the new rows to the server. By the way, if you use `datatype: "local"`, then you can just add the rows to `mydata` array, set new value of `data` parameter of jqGrid and then reload the grid. It saves the usage of `addRowData` (which takes some time in working with DOM) and after reloading the grid you should have the same results.

Comment: @Oleg I know, I'm not sure about OP's scenario either. But the scenario I have is that when the user clicks a button the system should add a new row in the grid. If you check the jsfiddle I posted in my last comment (which is based on the jsfiddle of Yauhen.F) you can see it working. And I think is a valid scenario to use addRowData. And if you remove the line with the "reloadGrid" you will see how pagination and sorting won't work.

Comment: @MarianoDesanze: I confirmed already that the usage of `reloadGrid` in your demo would be the solution in your scenario. On the other side the most scenarios of the usage of `addRowData` are either wrong or be slow (at least for large number of rows). Reloading the grid uses just local `data`. `addRowData` do 2 things: add the row to local `data` **and** make some changes on DOM, which takes time and which are not want you want. In my previous comment I suggested you just make the modification in `data` only and then reload the grid. Look at http://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/aY59T/34/

Comment: @Oleg I get your point now. And I really appreciate your help. And you approach works perfect in that fiddle. But in my project the grid id column is actually named differently, and then I have to be able to delete the rows. So if I use your approach in there I get an incorrect index and the delete is deleting other items instead of deleting the ones I selected. So  I'll have to stick with addRowData for now. You can see the problem in here: http://jsfiddle.net/protron/aY59T/35/

Comment: @MarianoDesanze: You missing one more thing: the input data should contain rowid which default property name `id` instead of `uid` (see [here](https://free-jqgrid.github.io/getting-started/index.html)). Changing of the property fixes the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/aY59T/36/. Alternatively you can specify `localReader: { id: "uid" }` option of jqGrid http://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/aY59T/37/. Finally I'd recommend you to upgrade from old jqGrid 4.6 to [free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid) 4.15.2. "Free jqGrid" is the fork of jqGrid, which I develop starting with the end of 2014.

Answer (score 1):

Call refresh after add row `jQuery("#grid").trigger("reloadGrid");`